# Generating the unique sets of attributes into a new table?

Tags: sql, plsql

I currently need to make a table that holds the unique sets of attributes for another table. That is, I have a table that looks like this:

`Table A : columns = col 1, col2, col3, col4, col5`

And I need to produce this:

```
Table B : columns = columnName, value
col 1, col1attribute1
col 1, col1attribute2
col 1, col1attribute3
col 2, col2attribute1
col 3, col3attribute1
col 3, col3attribute2
```

Is there an easy way to do this with (PL)SQL alone? It seems simple enough if I do it programatically in Java, but ideally I'd like an sql-only solution if possible.

Comment: You mention (PL)SQL, is this on Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (COLUMN_NAME, VALUE) AS
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_1', COL_1 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_2', COL_2 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_3', COL_3 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_4', COL_4 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_5', COL_5 FROM TABLE_A;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use:

```
  SELECT * INTO table_b from (
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_1', COL_1 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_2', COL_2 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_3', COL_3 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_4', COL_4 FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 'COL_5', COL_5 FROM TABLE_A)a;
```

EDIT: as someone points out this works in postgres, (and I think sql server as well), from your PL/SQL tag, I assumed postgres as postegres is PL/pgSQL, hadn't noticed that until now.

Comment: This doesn't work, at least in Oracle, and from the PLSQL tag I had guessed that this was an Oracle question.  For it to work in Oracle you'd replace the "SELECT * INTO table_b from" with "INSERT INTO TABLE_B (COLUMN_NAME, VALUE)" - and the column list can really be left off in this case.  No downvote, just curious as to what database might allow the "SELECT * INTO..." syntax.

Comment: Postgres, which also is PL/SQL... hummm... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/static/sql-selectinto.html